# Replace NULL with SUBTOTAL and TOTAL in a ROLLUP

Tags: mysql, rollup, ifnull

I have tried to use IFNULL to replace the NULL fields returned by ROLLUP for subtotals and totals but it doesn't appear to be working.

Query:

```
select IFNULL(usergroups.name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
IFNULL(users.name, 'TOTAL') AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED,
..........
..........
and vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
group by DEALER, SERVICE_ADVISOR with ROLLUP;
```

Output:

```
DEALER          SERVICE_ADVISOR COMPLETED   IDENTIFIED  AUTHORISED
Aston Martin    Chris           3           664.56      0
Aston Martin    Graham          6           0           0
Aston Martin    (NULL)          15          664.56      0
Bentley         Sukraj          1           0           0
Bentley         Terry           4           0           0
Bentley         (NULL)          5           0           0
Jaguar          Emma            10          2448        1224
Jaguar          Paul            1           0           0
Jaguar          Simon           7           2754        918
Jaguar          (NULL)          18          5202        2142
(NULL)          (NULL)          2611        96591.62    42130.14
```

Desired Output:

```
DEALER          SERVICE_ADVISOR COMPLETED   IDENTIFIED  AUTHORISED
Aston Martin    Chris           3           664.56      0
Aston Martin    Graham          6           0           0
Aston Martin    TOTAL           15          664.56      0
Bentley         Sukraj          1           0           0
Bentley         Terry           4           0           0
Bentley         TOTAL           5           0           0
Jaguar          Emma            10          2448        1224
Jaguar          Paul            1           0           0
Jaguar          Simon           7           2754        918
Jaguar          TOTAL           18          5202        2142
GROUP           TOTAL           2611        96591.62    42130.14
```

Answer (score 8):

To resolve the issue with `COALESCE/IFNULL` still returning `NULL` for the `WITH ROLLUP` placeholders, you need to `GROUP BY` the table column names, rather than the aliased column expressions.

The issue is caused by the `GROUP BY` clause being specified on the aliased column expressions, because the aliases are assigned ***after*** the column expression is processed.
Resulting in the `WITH ROLLUP` `NULL` placeholders not being in the recordset to be evaluated by `COALESCE`.
Meaning the aliases `DEALER`, `SERVICE_ADVISOR` in the `GROUP BY` do not exist until ***after*** `IFNULL/COALESCE` have already been executed.
See MySQL [Handling of `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for more details.

**Example** [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4YeJbSPS158TFBMGp2r3Wg/2)

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  `amount` INTEGER,
  `created` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO foo
  (`amount`, `created`)
VALUES
  ('1', '2019'),
  ('2', '2019');
```

**Query #1** (Reproduce Issue)

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) AS amounts,
    COALESCE(created, 'Total') AS created_coalesce
FROM foo
GROUP BY created_coalesce WITH ROLLUP;

| amounts | created_coalesce |
| ------- | ---------------- |
| 3       | 2019             |
| 3       |                  |
```

**Query #2** (Corrected)

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) AS amounts,
    COALESCE(created, 'Total') AS created_coalesce
FROM foo
GROUP BY foo.created WITH ROLLUP;

| amounts | created_coalesce |
| ------- | ---------------- |
| 3       | 2019             |
| 3       | Total            |
```

---

### Use-Case Specific

**Example** [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9u7odVMQBqERSybq2tvFDk/0)

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(usergroups.name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
    COALESCE(users.name, 'TOTAL') AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
    COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED,
/* ... */
GROUP BY usergroups.name, users.name WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Query #1** (Original)

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(usergroups.name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
    COALESCE(users.name, 'TOTAL') AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
    COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED
/* ... */
GROUP BY DEALER, SERVICE_ADVISOR WITH ROLLUP;

| DEALER | SERVICE_ADVISOR | COMPLETED |
| ------ | --------------- | --------- |
| Foo    | Jane Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    | John Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    |                 | 2         |
|        |                 | 2         |
```

**Query #2** (Corrected)

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(usergroups.name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
    COALESCE(users.name, 'TOTAL') AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
    COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED
/* ... */
GROUP BY usergroups.name, users.name WITH ROLLUP;

| DEALER | SERVICE_ADVISOR | COMPLETED |
| ------ | --------------- | --------- |
| Foo    | Jane Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    | John Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    | TOTAL           | 2         |
| GROUP  | TOTAL           | 2         |
```

---

### Considerations

1. > With MySQL 5.7+ and [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) enabled, selected
   > non-aggregate columns that are not specified in the `GROUP BY` clause
   > will fail.  Meaning the following query will not work as expected: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9mGtTWL1VTJ7TRboN9PfxC/0)
   >
   > ```
   > SELECT COALESCE(YEAR(foo), 'foo') /* ... */ GROUP BY YEAR(foo) WITH ROLLUP
   > -> ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.foo_bar.foo' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
   > ```
2. > [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce),
   > [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if),
   > [`IF(... IS NULL)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)
   > and [`CASE WHEN ... IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)
   > will all function
   > similarly. Where `IFNULL` is the proprietary to MySQL and is a less
   > functional replacement of `COALESCE`. As `COALESCE` can accept more
   > than two parameters to check against `NULL`, returning the first `non-NULL` value.
   >
   > ```
   > mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 1, NULL);
   >        -> 1
   >
   > mysql> SELECT IFNULL(NULL, 1);
   >        -> 1
   >
   > mysql> SELECT IF(NULL IS NULL, 1, '');
   >        -> 1
   >
   > mysql> SELECT CASE WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN 1 END;
   >        -> 1
   > ```
3. > nullable columns in the `GROUP BY` as either aliases or column names, will result in the `NULL` values being
   > displayed as the `WITH ROLLUP` placeholder. This applies to using `WITH ROLLUP` in general. For example if
   > `users.name` can return `NULL`. [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/77k4P36CgZa9KLF556PeFS/0)
   >
   > ```
   > | DEALER | SERVICE_ADVISOR | COMPLETED | 
   > | ------ | --------------- | --------- | 
   > | Foo    | TOTAL           | 1         |
   > | Foo    | Jane Doe        | 1         |
   > | Foo    | John Doe        | 1         |
   > | Foo    | TOTAL           | 3         |
   > | GROUP  | TOTAL           | 3         |
   > ```

---

### Prevent `NULL` column values from being displayed

To ensure that nullable columns are not accidentally included, you would need to specify in the criteria to exclude them.

**Example** [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/GzoHjc8GHTQAZvwkFPDTh/0)

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(usergroups.name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
    COALESCE(users.name, 'TOTAL') AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
    COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED
FROM vcrs
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id = vcrs.uid
LEFT JOIN usergroups
ON usergroups.id = users.group_id
WHERE vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
AND users.name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY usergroups.name, users.name
WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Result**

```
| DEALER | SERVICE_ADVISOR | COMPLETED |
| ------ | --------------- | --------- |
| Foo    | Jane Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    | John Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    | TOTAL           | 2         |
| GROUP  | TOTAL           | 2         |
```

> Since `LEFT JOIN` is used on the `vcrs` table, `IS NOT NULL` must be
> applied to the `WHERE` clause, instead of the `ON` clause. As `LEFT JOIN` returns `NULL` for non-matching criteria. To circumvent the
> issue, use an `INNER JOIN` to limit the resultset to only those with
> matching `ON` criteria.

```
/* ... */
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id = vcrs.uid
AND users.name IS NOT NULL
/* ... */
WHERE vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
GROUP BY usergroups.name, users.name
WITH ROLLUP;
```

---

### Include `NULL` columns values

To explicitly include nullable column values, without duplicating the `WITH ROLLUP` placeholder name, you would need to utilize a derived table subquery to substitute the `NULL` value as a textual value.

**Example** [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGtfbCs3DhWm69P4YhntZT/0)

```sql
SELECT 
    COALESCE(v.usergroup_name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
    COALESCE(v.user_name, 'TOTAL') AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.uid) AS COMPLETED
FROM (
  SELECT
      usergroups.name AS usergroup_name,
      COALESCE(users.name, 'NULL') AS user_name,
      vcrs.uid
  FROM vcrs
  LEFT JOIN users
  ON users.id = vcrs.uid
  LEFT JOIN usergroups
  ON usergroups.id = users.group_id
  WHERE vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
) AS v
GROUP BY v.usergroup_name, v.user_name
WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Result**

```
| DEALER | SERVICE_ADVISOR | COMPLETED |
| ------ | --------------- | --------- |
| Foo    | Jane Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    | John Doe        | 1         |
| Foo    | NULL            | 1         |
| Foo    | TOTAL           | 3         |
| GROUP  | TOTAL           | 3         |
```

---

You can also optionally replace the `'NULL'` textual placeholder as desired and even display it as `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(v.usergroup_name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
    CASE v.user_name WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE COALESCE(v.user_name, 'TOTAL') END AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.uid) AS COMPLETED
FROM (
    /* ... */
) AS v
GROUP BY v.usergroup_name, v.user_name
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: This would create confusion in case there is grouping for a nullable field, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ChristosKarapapas updated my answer to explain the nullable columns issue and workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

I'm only 2 years too late, but since I came across the same issue as @the_gimlet I thought I'd post the answer.

So don't know if this is a mySQL versioning or something, but using mysql 5.6 I get the same problem... ifnull will not replace the rollup 'nulls'.

Simply get around this by making your rollup a subquery, and doing the ifnulls in the main select... annoying to repeat the select, but it works!

e.g. for example above

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(`DEALER`, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
  IFNULL(`SERVICE_ADVISOR`, 'TOTAL') AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
  `COMPLETED`,
  /* .......... */
FROM (SELECT 
        usergroups.name AS DEALER,
        users.name AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
        COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED,
      /* .......... */
      AND       vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
      GROUP BY  DEALER, SERVICE_ADVISOR with ROLLUP);
```

Comment: if nothing else, at least @the_gimlet now knows they weren't going mad :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT COALESCE(usergroups.name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
COALESCE(users.name, IF(usergroups.name IS NULL, 'TOTAL', 'SUBTOTAL')) AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED,
..........
..........
AND vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
GROUP BY DEALER, SERVICE_ADVISOR with ROLLUP;
```

Test:

```
mysql;root@localhost(playground)> select * from t;
+------+----------+-------+--------+
| id   | car      | state | tstamp |
+------+----------+-------+--------+
|    1 | toyota   | new   |   1900 |
|    2 | toyota   | old   |   1950 |
|    3 | toyota   | scrap |   1980 |
|    4 | mercedes | new   |   1990 |
|    5 | mercedes | old   |   2010 |
|    6 | tesla    | new   |   2013 |
+------+----------+-------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql;root@localhost(playground)> select car, sum(tstamp) from t group by car with rollup;
+----------+-------------+
| car      | sum(tstamp) |
+----------+-------------+
| mercedes |        4000 |
| tesla    |        2013 |
| toyota   |        5830 |
| NULL     |       11843 |
+----------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql;root@localhost(playground)> select coalesce(car, 'huhu'), sum(tstamp) from t group by car with rollup;
+-----------------------+-------------+
| coalesce(car, 'huhu') | sum(tstamp) |
+-----------------------+-------------+
| mercedes              |        4000 |
| tesla                 |        2013 |
| toyota                |        5830 |
| huhu                  |       11843 |
+-----------------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response - just tried your suggestion but it hasn't made a difference, still returning NULL as it did when I was using IFNULL....?

Comment: @the_gimlet Are you sure, you're not mixing something up? Works fine in my case. See my edited answer for proof.

Comment: I copied and pasted the COALESCE exactly as you wrote it, but there was no change in the output. The query includes joins, would that affect it at all?

Comment: The code should definitely work, your code too. If you see no difference, you're mixing something else up. Stupid question, don't take this offensive, but are you looking at a newly generated result?

Comment: no offence taken. yes i've re-run it a few times, switching back and forth between IFNULL and COALESCE but the result doesn't change. I am very new at this  but managed to get everything else working correctly. Strange, and very frustrating, that I've snagged on this one simple thing. what else could i have mixed up that would affect it?

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: works great! now only if i not replace null if it is the grant total column 

Comment: This works because the table column name `car` is used as opposed to an alias, which is applied prior to the rows benng grouped. `COALESCE()` and `IFNULL()` function similarly. If you use `COALESCE(car, 'huhu') AS car_name` ... `GROUP BY car_name` the same issue is experienced. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sCAsSDe2DmzMh1YdzWzpZV/0 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a case statement.
What you're saying is that under a certain condition replace the found value with the one specified. You can use multiple when/then statements depending on how customised you'd like the replacements to be.

```
select IFNULL(usergroups.name, 'GROUP') AS DEALER,
case when(users.name is null) then 'TOTAL' else users.name end AS SERVICE_ADVISOR,
COUNT(DISTINCT vcrs.uid) AS COMPLETED,
..........
..........
and vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
group by DEALER, SERVICE_ADVISOR with ROLLUP;
```